# Regularize time between rows in a pyspark dataframe with column-wise linear interpolation of numeric data

Tags: pyspark, interpolation

I am new to pyspark. I have this data:

```
# Sample data
data = [
    ("2023-10-16 00:00:00", 10, 100, "A"),
    ("2023-10-16 00:00:03", 20, 200, "B"),
    ("2023-10-16 00:00:08", 30, 300, "C"),
]

columns = ["TimeStamp", "Signal1", "Signal2", "Category"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

I have my signal in columns Signal1 and Signal2. The column Category contains non-numeric data. What I want to achieve is regularization of time given a fixed time step, say 1 second. I also want to make sure that in the new rows I will insert, numerical columns are linearly interpolated between the values from the original data frame. The non-numerical columns should be filled in from the latest non-null value forward, going from top to bottom of the column. So I would like to achieve this:

regularized_data:

```
+-------------------+-------+-------+--------+
|          TimeStamp|Signal1|Signal2|Category|
+-------------------+-------+-------+--------+
|2023-10-16 00:00:00| 10.00000|  100.0000|  A|
|2023-10-16 00:00:01| 13.33333|  133.3333|  A|
|2023-10-16 00:00:02| 16.66666|  166.6666|  A|
|2023-10-16 00:00:03| 20.00000|  200.0000|  B|
|2023-10-16 00:00:04| 22.00000|  220.0000|  B|
|2023-10-16 00:00:05| 24.00000|  240.0000|  B|
|2023-10-16 00:00:06| 26.00000|  260.0000|  B|
|2023-10-16 00:00:07| 28.00000|  280.0000|  B|
|2023-10-16 00:00:08| 30.00000|  300.0000|  C|
+-------------------+-------+-------+--------+
```

For the context, temporal regularization is a requirement for the application of the fast Fourier transform, which I want to apply to the signal.

I would be grateful for any pointers in the right direction. Thank you!

I have my code in python using pandas but I really have to adapt it to pyspark. I have tried chatGPT-4 on this, but the advice I am given is no good.